# Crash reporting library independent integration for Android and iOS module/framework

Tags: android, ios, crash-reports

We have one unique need, where we want to integrate crash reporting tool inside Android library (jar file) and iOS framework, independent of the host(consumer) application.

HockeyApp or Crashlytic follows singleton approach so it can be used only at one place, either in application or library. Is there any other library or provision so that we can independently report uncaught exception from the library?

Comment: Fabric is good to use and also integrate firebase with fabric.

Comment: check this one http://docs.splunk.com/Documentation/Mint/1.0/ProductOverview/AboutSplunkMINT

Comment: In case of fabric, if host application integrate any other tool or fabric itself then crash will get reported by the application because it will override defaultUncaughthandler.